# What type of project needs to be created for C++/CLI?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am writing a wrapper for my native C++ methods in C++/CLI which will expose them to C#. Now I am using Visual Studio 2008. Can any one tell  me what type of project I need to create so that my wrapper will be exposed to C#. I see in Visual Studio 2008 there are different types of projects under Visual C++--->CLR---->

```
class library,
CLR Empty Project,
Windows form control library,
CLR Console Application,
Windows Forms Application,
Windows Service
```

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to create the project of type Class Library. The most important thing is to specify the "Common Language Runtime Support" option (set to "Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)") in the Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General

This will allow you to use the

```
#pragma managed
... use your native stuff here
#pragma unmanaged
```

pragmas and link with the native .lib files.

See this link for subtle details

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_managed/interop/article.php/c6867/Consuming-Unmanaged-C-Class-Libraries-from-NET-Clients.htm

There is a catch (not mentioned in this article) for 64-bit builds. The "Linker->Input->Force Symbol References" must be set to "_*DllMainCRTStartup" for 64-bit and to "*_DllMainCRTStartup@12" for 32-bit.

Comment: thank you for quick response, under general "common language runtime support" is see like four options
1.) Common language runtime support(/clr)
2.) /clr:pure
3.) /clr:safe
4.) /clr:oldsyntax

so which one of these four need to be selected. aand under "Character Set" do i need to select the "Unicode Character set" or "No Set"

Comment: "Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)" - this will allow mixing native and managed code in one assembly.

Comment: The character set is mostly irrelevant