# Passing Structure to C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, pinvoke

I am writing code to parse a complicated string in C++ and create a tree from it. I would like to use C# in Visual Studio 2017 to call a native c++ method that returns a vector of nodes.

A Node looks like:

```
class node
{
  public:
    std::vector<node> subnodes;
    std::string name;
};
```

and the c++ function might look like:

```
class noderizer
{
public:
    node getNodes(std::string str);
};
```

what is the most efficient (coding time with secondary consideration for speed) way to call the `noderizer::getNodes(...)` member and create a equivalent class for c#?

I am assuming that the best route is to create a duplicate class definition in c# and then copy marshal the native `std::strings` into managed `Strings`"

```
public class node
{
    public string  name = string.Empty;
    List<node> integers = new List<node>();
}
```

It's not clear if [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) contains the latest information for c++ interop, but a related article on [wrapping c++ native classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235281.aspx) for use in c# indicates that I could most likely just wrap `noderizer` native c++ as `noderizer * m_Impl;` and then call the `getNodes` member and copy over each parameter. Is this the correct methodology?

Comment: Yes, you can used managed C++, expose your C++ methods via COM, and there is more.

Comment: What's the benefit of having the same tree structure in C++ *and* in C#? It really depends of what the usage of all this will be. Usually (especially when you own both sides, managed and unmanaged), you devote a language to a usage/scenario, you don't need to do/code everything in both langage.

Comment: @wp78de I don't know that there is any explicit benefit, I just don't know to what extend the data structure in c++ is available in c#. My understanding is that the strings vectors must be manually transferred between managed and unmanaged code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use pInvoke as per your first referenced article, but the objects you are returning seem quite complicated. I think you will have a heck of a time with data marshalling if you're not already well versed (and even then). pInvoke is great for simple calls to C libraries where data marshalling is basic, but it gets very complicated very fast. This is not good for your situation.

The second article is closer to where you want to look. That being said, you have to consider whether you want to be wrapping a managed class or just calling a function that takes a string and returns your tree in managed format (i.e. it makes a copy rather than wrap unmanaged data). By your post it seems like you just need the latter.

Your best option is to use C++/CLI. Check out [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-minutes). I am confident that taking this approach will make light work of your task. I won't attempt to explain the subject as the article above does a very good job. In essence, you will be able write functions with both managed and unmanaged data types, where all the data marshalling is built into the environment. A simple cast will marshal the data for you behind the scenes. As a big bonus, debugging is great as you can step from C# to C++/CLI to C++ code and back.

In the article above, the author does describe how to wrap an unmanaged class, which you can well do, but your problem will still be with data conversion.

I would approach your problem in 4 steps:

1. Write a static function `getNodes()` in C++/CLI that you can call from C# as any regular static method, passing a `string` as an argument. The article above will help you with that. Also [See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10642441/7159784) when creating the C++/CLI project.
2. `getNodes()` will use your C++ code to create a `tree` in its unmanaged form.
3. Use `getNodes()` to convert the `tree` from unmanaged to managed form.
4. Return the result to the caller in C#.

your declaration will look something like this, where the `Node` is your managed calss, `ref` keyword signifies that the class is managed, and `^` is the managed version of `*`.

```
public ref class noderizer
{
public:
    static Node^ getNodes(String ^mStr);
};
```

Here `getNodes()` calls your C++ function and does the data conversion. I don't think it will take you long to figure it out. 
Once you get a hang of the syntax, I think you will find it quite intuitive to use if you are already familiar with C# and C++.

As for performance, unless you're making thousands of consecutive calls or need critical real time data, it should not be an issue. One thing I would say though, if you're concerned with performance, you should write the pure C++ code in a separate purely unmanaged dll. I can't find the article for the life of me, but I remember looking at some benchmarks of executing purely unmanaged long running code block that was compiled inside the C++/CLI dll vs calling the exact same code that was compiled inside its own purely unmanaged dll. If I recall correctly, the separate dll was something like 3x faster.